# Angular reactive form subscribing

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

I subscribed to valueChanges event to Angular's reactive form. I need to react on user inputs to prevent or correct his inputs, I tried few approaches but no one works as expected. While subscribing I get an `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error.

```
const controlArray = <FormArray> this.formArray.get('items');
    this.formArray.get('items').valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
      val.forEach(s => {
        controlArray.controls.forEach(control => {
          const con = control.get('symbol');
          if (con.value === s.symbol) {
            con.setValue(s.symbol.toUpperCase());
          }
        });
      });
    });
```

In this case I just want change each letter input to uppercase. How can I do that? Or maybe there is simpler way than few iterates on each keyboard event?

I also tried put `(change)="function(value)"` but it's called only when I use `enter` on keyboard :/

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier way to achieve this. Use the `input` directive. Let's assume you have an object `book` and you want to set its field `title` to upper case while the user enters a text.

**HTML-Template**

```
<input id="book-title" name="book-title" (input)="book.title = book.title.toUpperCase();"/>
```

Comment: Here you go. If this answer helped you, please don't forget to mark it as solution.

Comment: hmm It doesn't work, just nothing happens. Anyway I need more actions to be executed besides toUpperCase function, thanks anyway. Btw this is how my input looks like actually:
` <input name="symbol" minlength="1" maxlength="1" (input)="vatCat.value.symbol = vatCat.value.symbol.toUpperCase();" type="text" formControlName="symbol">`
It is in FormGroup which is in FormArray

Comment: That's strange. Okay, I'm using the template-driven approach instead of model-driven, but this should make no difference here..

Answer (score 1):

**Maximum call stack size exceeded** it's because you find yourself into an infinite loop, while watching you change a value than the watcher it's called again and it changes the value and the watcher is called again and it changes the value and again, and again, and again..

What you can do is to **not emit** the event inside your observer thanks to the native  patchValue method:

```
    this.myCustomForm.patchValue({
      fieldSimbol: this.myCustomForm.value.fieldSimbol.toUpperCase()
    }, { emitEvent: false })
```

Then you can include it in a generic buildForm function

```
buildForm() {

//...FormControls
this.myForm= new FormGroup({
  fieldSimbol: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
});

//..ValidationMessages
this.validationMessages = {
'fieldSimbol': [
    { type: 'required', message: 'Please fill this field' }
  ]
}

//..observe value change
this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe((data) => {
  //..other stuff
  //..some controls

  //..what you probably need
  this.myCustomForm.patchValue({
   fieldSimbol: this.myCustomForm.value.fieldSimbol.toUpperCase()
  }, { emitEvent: false })
});
```

}